# How to focus html textfield using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, textfield

Can somebody tell me how to focus the html textfield using JavaScript?
I am a total novice in programming and just starting to learn. I have here the code in which
I want to set the cursor in the textfield.

> **test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 function parseTest() {
  var elem_1 = document.getElementById('input_1');
  var elem_2 = document.getElementById('input_2');

  var inp_1 = elem_1.value;
  var inp_2 = elem_2.value;

  if (inp_1 == "" && inp_2 == "") {
   alert("You need to enter integers!!!");
   elem_1.focus();
  }else if (inp_1 == ""){
   alert("You need to enter Integer 1!!!");
   elem_1.focus();
  }else if (inp_2 == ""){
   alert("You need to enter Integer 2!!!");
   elem_2.focus();
  }else {
   if (!parseInt(inp_1) || !parseInt(inp_2)) alert ("Enter Integers only!!!");
   else alert("Correct Inputs!!!");
  } 
 }
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <form name="myform">
  <input type="text" id="input_1" name="input_1" /><br />
  <input type="text" id="input_2" name="input_2" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Check!" onclick="parseTest();" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a total novice so please be patient. Please help...

Comment: your code __will__ focus the input box...what exactly is the issue?

Comment: You say something about focus and later you say something about putting the cursor on top of the textboxfield which of these do you want to achieve?

Comment: The issue is its not working... I don't know why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code does that - however, right afterwards, it submits the form and redisplays the page, that's why you don't see the focus happening.

Simply add a `return false;` to your function call in `onclick`, like so:

```
<input type="submit" value="Check!" onclick="parseTest(); return false;" />
```

Comment: BTW, if you later need to actually submit the form, you need to do it with Javascript. Checkout http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml for example.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you dont want to submit after each button click.
You can do it another way:
1. If you want just check input, without subiting the form: use "button" input type

```
<input type="button" value="Check!" onclick="parseTest();" />
```

2. if you want submit if all is correct: use it like this:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
     function parseTest() {
      var elem_1 = document.getElementById('input_1');
      var elem_2 = document.getElementById('input_2');

      var inp_1 = elem_1.value;
      var inp_2 = elem_2.value;

      if (inp_1 == "" && inp_2 == "") {
       alert("You need to enter integers!!!");
       elem_1.focus();
      }else if (inp_1 == ""){
       alert("You need to enter Integer 1!!!");
       elem_1.focus();
      }else if (inp_2 == ""){
       alert("You need to enter Integer 2!!!");
       elem_2.focus();
      }else {
       if (!parseInt(inp_1) || !parseInt(inp_2)) alert ("Enter Integers only!!!");
       else 
       {
          alert("Correct Inputs!!!");
          return true;
       }
      } 
      return false;
     }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
     <form name="myform">
      <input type="text" id="input_1" name="input_1" /><br />
      <input type="text" id="input_2" name="input_2" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Check!" onclick="return parseTest();" />
     </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```